# Wordpress: <script src="?ver=1.10.2"></script> being loaded out of nowhere

Tags: php, wordpress

**Website:**

http://ramprate.com/design1/

You'll find a script tag inside `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ramprate.com/design1?ver=1.10.2"></script>
```

I don't know where this is coming from. I deactivated all the plugins one at a time, and the tag was still being loaded after every deactivation. I removed `wp_head()` from the header file, but the tag was still being loaded inside the `<body>`

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out where it's being queued but couldn't. I found that the version of jQuery on this wordpress installation is 1.10.2 ( WP Version 3.6 ) - so I guess it's related to loading jQuery. A grep for `1.10.2` inside wp-content yields no result either.

Any thoughts on where this is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that a bug in 'Better Wordpress Minify' can cause this. See also this official support thread: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-36-jquery-enqueued-but-wrong-script-written-after

Comment: I should've answered this myself. This was an issue with the BWP plugin

Answer (score 0):

It's more than likely being loaded with the `wp_enqueue_script` from a plugin, using the API you can disable this if you want to. Unsure why you really need to.

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>
```

You will find that `$ver` is set to `true` in the script call.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script